# When to use a diamond operator with a method call in Java in form of .<ClassName>methodName()?

Tags: java, generics

Sometimes I see examples of using a diamond operator in the method invocation.

An example of syntax is:

```
.<ClassName>methodName()
```

I'm not sure that I understand entirely in which condition there is a case for such use.
Didn't find an explanation of that in the references.

May you explain that case or suggest a source of information where I can find an explanation?

I am providing working an example down below. This example uses RxJava2.
There `Flowable.<Integer>create(emitter -> emit(emitter), BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)` doesn't compile without `<Integer>` because the method emit accepts `FlowableEmitter<Integer> emitter`.

```
import io.reactivex.BackpressureStrategy;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.FlowableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flowable.<Integer>create(emitter -> emit(emitter), BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.computation(), true,2)
                .map(data -> data * 1)
                .subscribe(Sample::process,
                        err -> System.out.println("ERROR: " + err),
                        () -> System.out.println("DONE"));

    }

    public static void process(int value) {
        System.out.println(value);
        sleep(1000);
    }

    private static void emit(FlowableEmitter<Integer> emitter) {
        int count = 0;

        while(count < 10) {
            count++;

            System.out.println("Emitting ..." + count);
            emitter.onNext(count);
            sleep(500);
        }
    }

    private static boolean sleep(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

When I try to simulate a similar case with plain Java it doesn't work. What I understand wrong?

```
public class Sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericClass.<Integer>genericMethod(param -> processParam(param));

    }

    private static void processParam(GenericClass<Integer> b) {
        }
    }

}

class GenericClass <T> {
    public static <T> GenericClass<T> genericMethod(GenericInterface<T> genericinterface) {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }
}

interface GenericInterface <T> {
    T doJob();
}
```

Comment: It's like using `new ArrayList<Integer>`. Usually it can be omitted, but sometimes the compiler can't infer the generic type. This occurs mostly when there are some chained method calls, and the final generic type isn't given until the last step (or perhaps in an intermediary step). By providing the explicit generic-type for the method, you're helping the compiler (or perhaps yelling at it) by telling what the type should be.

Comment: The `Foo.<Bar>baz()` syntax is for when the **method** is generic (not the class itself). So when the method itself introduces a generic type, then this is the way to explicitly state the type, in case auto-inference fails. Auto-inference usually fails in complex setups, when the compiler is "*too dumb*" to follow whats going on, type-wise.

Comment: It's not `<ClassName>.methodName()` it's `.<ClassName>methodName()`

Comment: The diamond operator is when you *don't* specify the type (`<>`).  Does anyone know the correct name for the OPs question?  I've tried looking it up and it's hard to find.

Comment: Have somebody managed to simulate this case with plain Java?

Comment: @markspace, this is from Java language specification:  A parameterized type is a class or interface type of the form C<T1,...,Tn>, where C
is the name of a generic class or interface, and <T1,...,Tn> is a list of type arguments
that denote a particular parameterization of the generic class or interface.

Comment: @markspace The JLS just lists it as a form of invocation expression but I don't think it is given a particular name/term. IIRC, it just calls it things like "invocation with explicit type arguments" or something like that.

Comment: Thanks folks and @Sweeper.  I found that a web search for "java generic method invocation parameter" worked pretty well ("method invocation" seems to help a lot).  The tutorial calls this "explicitly" specifying the type (as opposed to inferring the type). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ClassName.<Type>methodName(...)` is one of the forms of method invocations in Java. There are many other forms as listed in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12):

```
MethodInvocation:
  MethodName ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) <--- this is the form in question
  ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] ) 
  TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )

TypeArguments:
  < TypeArgumentList >
TypeArgumentList:
  TypeArgument {, TypeArgument}
```

Inside the `<...>`, you are supposed to write the type arguments for each of the type parameters of the generic method explicitly.

Note that `ClassName<Type>.methodName` is not one of the forms.

The main thing you missed in your attempt to simulate this behaviour in plain Java is that `GenericInterface.doJob` should take a parameter, because the lambda you pass in has a parameter:

```
param -> processParam(param)
^^^^^
```

This parameter should be of type `GenericClass<T>`, because that is what `processParam` takes.

```
interface GenericInterface <T> {
    void doJob(GenericClass<T> param);
}
```

This is analogous to the [`subscribe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/FlowableOnSubscribe.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.FlowableEmitter-) method in `FlowableOnSubscribe<T>`, which is what `Flowable.create` takes as argument.

Note that `subscribe` takes a different type from what `Flowable.create` returns, but we are taking the same type as what `GenericClass.genericMethod` returns. This still simulates the same behaviour of "writing the type parameter explicitly compiles but omitting it produces an error", so I will not bother to create a new type.

Now you get the same behaviour as the `Flowable.create` method in RxJava:

```
GenericClass.genericMethod(param -> processParam(param)); // error
GenericClass.<Integer>genericMethod(param -> processParam(param)); // OK
```

This is because Java's type inference algorithm is not powerful enough to infer the type correctly in the first case.

There is still a difference between this and RxJava though - `Flowable.create` takes a `FlowableOnSubscribe<T>`, which has a ``

Answer (score 0):

You can expand your example to:

```
class Sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericClass.genericMethod(new GenericInterface<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer doJob(? param) {
                return param;
            }
        }));

    }

    private static void processParam(GenericClass<Integer> b) {
    }
}

}

class GenericClass <T> {
    public static <T> GenericClass<T> genericMethod(GenericInterface<T> genericinterface) {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }
}

interface GenericInterface <T> {
    T doJob();
}
```

As you can see your lambda expression expects some input parameter "? param" which does not match the signature of GenericInterface#doJob. If you change your code to this:

```
lass Sample2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericClass.genericMethod(param -> processParam(param)); // <- this compiles now without any "<..>"

    }

    private static void processParam(GenericClass<Integer> b) {
    }
}

}

class GenericClass <T> {
    public static <T> GenericClass<T> genericMethod(GenericInterface<T> genericinterface) {
        return new GenericClass<T>();
    }
}

interface GenericInterface <T> {
    T doJob(T param);
}
```

When you struggle with lamdas and Functional Interfaces try expanding them to their anonymous inner class counterparts. This can help your IDE to give your better feet back and makes mistakes like this more obvious.